How does SQL Server set the value of uses_native_compilation?
Running ALTER on a TVF with the NATIVE_COMPILATION option resets the uses_native_compilation value in sys.sql_modules to 0.
Let's assume there is a TVF called dbo.fn:
create function dbo.fn()
returns table
with native_compilation, schemabinding
as
    return select 1 as result;
go

This function has 1 in the uses_native_compilation column in sys.sql_modules after creation.
Next, I need to execute an ALTER as a result of some logical changes or whatever. Let us keep it as simple as possible:
alter function dbo.fn()
returns table
with native_compilation, schemabinding
as
    return select 1 as result;
go

i.e. a simple ALTER, even without changing the function body, results in uses_native_compilation in sys.sql_modules being set to 0. Even though the text in the "definition" column might say "...with native_compilation...", it doesn't actually mean that anymore. TVF become non-native.
This behavior leads to some negative outcomes:

Attempting to execute ALTER again results in an error:


Cannot ALTER a non-native module into a natively compiled module. Omit WITH NATIVE_COMPILATION or drop and recreate the module.


Attempting to create a natively compiled module that uses this function results in an error:


Object 'dbo.fn' is not a memory optimized table or a natively compiled inline table-valued function and cannot be accessed from a natively compiled module.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?
Script to reproduce:
drop function if exists dbo.fn
go

create function dbo.fn()
returns table
with native_compilation, schemabinding
as
    return select 1 as result;
go

-- 1
select uses_native_compilation from sys.sql_modules where object_id = object_id('dbo.fn')
go

alter function dbo.fn()
returns table
with native_compilation, schemabinding
as
    return select 1 as result;
go

-- 0
select uses_native_compilation from sys.sql_modules where object_id = object_id('dbo.fn')
go

Reproduced in 2019 (I'm interested in) and 2022:

the latest SQL Server 2022 Developer. Just installed, no extra configuration was made.

Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM) - 16.0.1000.6 (X64)

SQL Server 2019 Developer.

Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU28)(KB5039747) - 15.0.4385.2 (X64)

SQL Server 2019 Developer.

Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)
If you can't reproduce when running CREATE and ALTER sequentially in different batches, as I failed with 15.0.2000.5, then try using this script with a loop (tests showed the need for a delay of up to 65 seconds before ALTER affects native, no idea why):
declare @dt datetime2(7) = current_timestamp;

while exists (select 1 from sys.sql_modules where object_id = object_id('dbo.fn') and uses_native_compilation = 1)
begin
    waitfor delay '00:00:01';

    exec('alter function dbo.fn()
returns table
with native_compilation, schemabinding
as
    return select 1 as result;');
end

select datediff(MILLISECOND, @dt, current_timestamp), current_timestamp, uses_native_compilation from sys.sql_modules where object_id = object_id('dbo.fn')
go


Also posted on the feedback site https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/39b04c9b-6b90-ef11-95f6-000d3ae2b698


tests showed the need for a delay of up to 65 seconds before ALTER affects native, no idea why

If I understand what you're saying correctly, and I know your example uses a table-valued function, but I assume the following is also true for them, as the Microsoft docs state the following in Scalar User-Defined Functions for In-Memory OLTP:

When you alter a natively compiled, scalar user-defined function, the application remains available while the operation is being run and the new version of the function is being compiled.

I wonder if what you're seeing is just the state of uses_native_compilation while it's in the middle of still being compiled natively, but also remaining available. Perhaps if you wait long enough, that'll eventually resolve to show the correct value?

Thank you for your feedback. I was unable to get 0 as a result of consecutive batch runs on only one system out of three. When there is 0, it will never go back to 1 on its own, no matter how long you wait. Then you can only drop and create to make it native (1) again. It seems that CREATE is the only correct option for native TVFs. But I can't find any confirmation of this anywhere and SQL Server allows you to run ALTER.

@ПавелСивоплясов "It seems that CREATE is the only correct option for native TVFs. But I can't find any confirmation of this anywhere and SQL Server allows you to run ALTER." - Well the docs I linked say ALTER is allowed too.
